# Why are "my tags" different from my favorite tags?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, sidebar

In the right column of [Unanswered | my tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags) sub-tab I see six tags:

[image: mytags]

But my list of favorite tags is very different: it has over 50 tags but does **not** include [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis), [linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra), [analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis), or [believe it or not] [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework).  Meta.SO post [How to remove some of "my tags"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19497/224469), the answer given there, and the experience of commenters on this post suggest that what I'm seeing is not normal behavior. The "my tags" list should be auto-populated only for users without favorite tags; for others it coincides with the list of favorite tags.

Accordingly, I'm retagging this post as [bug](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: For me, all and only my favourite tags are listed there.

Comment: I want to guess, and say that [tag:fourier-analysis] is one of your "favourite" tags. Looking at your user profile, the other tags in the "My Tags" list above are the tags you've answered the most questions in, even if you haven't received the most votes in these tags. I would **speculate** that if you have less than six favourited tags, the remainder are filled with the tags you've been the most active in, regardless of votes received.  (Please note that my speculation could very well be incorrect.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thanks for trying to help. `fourier-analysis` is indeed among my favorite tags. However, so is `differential-equations`, so this does not explain why FA beat DE. Also, I have over 50 favorited tags, so the software shouldn't feel the need to add its own.

Comment: Yikes!! This goes to prove that I have no idea how the "My Tags" works.  Not even the faintest clue.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Maybe only developers know... Lord_Farin said that in his case my_tags = favorite_tags, is it the same for you?

Comment: Yes, my "My Tags" = my "Favorite Tags".

Comment: I don't have any favorite tags. It appears that SE decided "My tags" = my tags with the highest number of votes, in descending order according to number of answers.

Comment: @Martin I see you participated in 79 tags; how many of them were selected for "my tags"?

Comment: They selected six tags.

Comment: @ˈjuː.zɚ79365 Same for me as well, even the order of "my fav" and "my tags" are the same.

Comment: @Brahadeesh: there really isn't much point in retagging a **completed bug report** from 7 years ago. Since the bug has been fixed, other people are unlikely to run into this problem.

Comment: @WillieWong Pardon me, I really am facepalming right now. I'll remember to switch on my brain next time.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what is the problem you are facing, but I can't replicate:

- I've set the same favorite tags as you
- I've navigated to the my tags page

Here's what I see:

[image]

The behavior you are reporting is consistent with having no preferences set, in which case the tags shown are the ones you are active in (similarly to the ones in your [public user page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/79365/ju-z79365?tab=tags)).

Since the report is more than 6 months old, it might have been fixed but not retagged, so that's what I am doing. If the problem is persisting please try to find more repro steps so I can fix the issue.

Comment: It hasn't been fixed; I have the same issue. Steps to reproduce: 1. Create an account. Do not select any favorite tags.  2. Answer enough questions so that the system will automatically designate some tags as "my tags". 3. Select some tags as favorites. 4. Observe that the automatically chosen "my tags" do not change, ever - even if the level of activity in favorite tags is now higher.

Comment: I suspect that would be caching. I'll try again, but those steps don't seem enough.

Comment: In case it helps to locate the problem, note that (in my case) "my tags" are not only different from "favorite tags"; they are also non-functional. The page with Unanswered/My Tags always has 0 questions (tested on different platforms, over the period of about a week). [Reported here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12621/123116).